# I don't know what is wrong with this python code

Tags: python, function

```
class FC():
    def data(self, a, b):
        self.n1 = a
        self.n2 = b

    def add(self):
        return (self.n1 + self.n2)
    >>> def pbnc(start, num):
        pb = FC()
        pb.data(start, start)
        while (num > 0):
            print(pb.add())
            pb.data(pb.n2, pb.add())
            num -= 1


>>> def pbnc(1, 10)
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'm currently learning 'Class' in python. And I can't find the wrong thing in this code. Is it wrong to use classes in other functions?

Comment: Add indentation after def pbnc

Comment: This looks like you're typing this into an interactive python repl? If so, the syntax error could be because you have `def` before calling the `pbnc` function. The `def` keyword is only for _defining_ functions.

Answer (score 0):

Appears to be a simple indentation error, this should be fine:

```py
class FC():
    def data(self, a, b):
        self.n1 = a
        self.n2 = b

    def add(self):
        return (self.n1 + self.n2)

    def pbnc(self, start, num):
        pb = FC()
        pb.data(start, start)
        while (num > 0):
            print(pb.add())
            pb.data(pb.n2, pb.add())
            num -= 1
'''
# Uncomment this part if you want this method outside of the class
def pbnc(start, num):
    pb = FC()
    pb.data(start, start)
    while (num > 0):
        print(pb.add())
        pb.data(pb.n2, pb.add())
        num -= 1
'''
```